# How to get names of files and folder on server and generate json for android

Tags: php, android, android-json

**I'm using these code to get list of files of a folder on server**

```
<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('/')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            //$thelist = $thelist.$file.'<br>';
            $thelist = $thelist.$file."\r\n";
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
 echo $thelist;
?>
```

**It is work fine, but i need to get files name with json array,
**but i don't know how to change it to get files name with json array just like**

```
{
    "links": [
        {
                "item": "1"
                "name": "fun1.PNG",
                "url": "/projects/fancy/fun1.PNG",
                "file": {
                    "filetype": "PNG",
                    "filesize": "650400"
                }
        },
        {
                "item": "2"
                "name": "fun2.PNG",
                "url": "/projects/fancy/fun2.PNG",
                "file": {
                    "filetype": "PNG",
                    "filesize": "450200"
                }
        },
        {
                "item": "3"
                "name": "fun3.PNG",
                "url": "/projects/fancy/fun3.PNG",
                "file": {
                    "filetype": "PNG",
                    "filesize": "340500"
                }
        },
    ]   
}
```

**i try also these codes**

```
 $thelist = array();
 if ($handle = opendir('.pic')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist[] = $file;
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
 echo json_encode($thelist);
```

**and in android i try to get json with these code**

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_all_products, params);
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
```

and i have this eror in logcat :

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

**so can anyone help me?**

Comment: post your full json parse code...

Comment: First i need json file i try example but i have no idea how to prepare .json file next my job is parsing... thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-Example)

Comment: thanks its work for me but how to get all file link in json file using php to getlist of file and folder for url purpose...
and my server having a lot of files like from 1 to 1000 files and all files have different name its difficult to write any best way to get all file name and than generate json file